# How Can I Use Fat Free Framework's Autoloader With Composer Compatible Libraries

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, fat-free-framework

I currently use the F3 autoloader to load F3 from `/lib/f3` and my app code from `/app`

My config for AUTOLOAD is `AUTOLOAD="lib/f3/;app/;`

So now I can do things like

```
$user = New \Models\User;
echo \Template::instance()->render('layout.html');
```

I want to also autoload other libraries but I seem to be having trouble. When I add them to `/lib` I also change the autoload:  `AUTOLOAD="lib/f3/;app/;lib/;`

For example, lets try this class:
https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class

I put `S3.php` in `/lib` I also put it in `/lib/S3`
...Still I cant do things like

```
$s3 = new \S3(....);   
$s3 = new S3(....);   
$s3 = new \S3\S3(....);
```

Nothing works without   `require_once 'lib/S3/S3.php';`

I have the same problem with Swiftmailer, MPDF and anything else I try.

What am I missing here? How can I easily install Composer compatible libraries which should autoload?

Comment: Well, it's just you. It works for me. I put the S3.php in my lib folder and F3 loaded it automatically, when I created a new object of it. Also tried to put the S3.php in to lib/S3/ and added lib/S3/ to my `AUTOLOAD` var, since `new \S3\S3` won't work, because the class has no namespace called `S3`

Comment: I think you should post your guidelines as an answer, my mistake was there, the class didnt have an S3 namespace.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me when it comes to Composer: in your F3's index.php require composer autoloader:

```
require_once 'PATH_TO_YOUR/vendor/autoload.php';
```

And it will load all your Composer files. Simple.

F3 framework creators build their own autoloader but it doesn't stop you from loading Composers' ([see this thread on F3's GitHub](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/issues/786))